# Should something be done about [query-by-example]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75929879/15261914) posted today, and it's tagged with [query-by-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-by-example).

Seeing no usage guidance, I looked at the list of questions tagged with it. It is originally from NHibernate/Hibernate/Spring/iBatis/JPA's "query by example", which makes sense but seems rather niche. Beyond that, but still related, it has been used for a [question about Access 2007's Query by Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10736007/15261914) and such. There are a few other questions that it might fit (databases, Django, etc.). However, some of the questions are simply using it in the sense of "here's a code example and my question" or "give me code examples" (see the question I linked at the beginning, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53551167/15261914), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75928097/15261914), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56051905/15261914)).

There are currently 94 open questions with it, and no usage guidance or tag wiki.
I'm not familiar with the Java things, but it does seem like a rather niche tag.
There are questions that are misusing it.

Should something be done about it? Should mistagged questions be retagged? Should it be made more specific (just the Java frameworks or something)? Or should it be removed completely?

At the very least, some usage guidance would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Please alert me to incorrect tags or failure to follow any protocols; this is my first post on Meta.

Comment: The oldest question tagged with this is [Is there a good documentation of NHibernate's query by example feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153273/2821954), which seems to refer to the same concept [Query by Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example).